# how i can put an image as background under multiple components on reatcjs

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-hooks

i want to put an image as background image where multiple components like video component login component bottom component floats on top of it. what would be the exact code pattern for this this on react as i am new to it. All the video component and other component goes here. The code is like this below:

```
import React from 'react'
import Video from './Video.js'
import './Home.css'
import logo from './images/background.png'

    function Home() {
        return (
            <div className="home">
               <img src={ logo } />
            </div>
        ) 
    }
    
    export default Home
```

Comment: Use `background-image` style for the topmost parent component

Comment: what's the syntax for that?

Answer (score 0):

You should make a parent component and use that parent component to wrap the child component so that the parent component appears as an image overlay above child comp.

```
import React from 'react'
import Video from './Video.js'
import './Home.css'
import logo from './images/background.png'

    function Parent() {
        return (
            <div className="home" style={{background: url(logo)}}>
               {...props.children}
            </div>
        ) 
    }
    
    export default Home
```

now use this parent component as -

```
<Parent>
    <Video src={videourl} >
</Parent>
```

Comment: <Parent>
    <Video src={videourl} >
</Parent>
where do i have to use this code.

Comment: {...props.children} is basically your child component when you wrap your child components inside the parent component

Comment: its says url is not defined

Comment: it should be ```style={{backgroundImage: `url(${logo})`}}```?

Comment: whats the proper code syntax if i want to just put some text over image like we write on a banner.